SyntaxError: Invalid token when using an exclamation point within an EJS output tag
<body>
        <h1>Home Page</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Name: <%= restaurant.name %></li>
            <li>Address: <%= restaurant.address %></li>
            <li>Phone: <%= restaurant.phone %></li>
            <li>
                <%= restaurant.isOpen === true ? "Yes, we are open!" : "No, we are
                closed" %>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>

Using Node.js, on localhost:3000,
The above code does not work and gives the following error:
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in /Users/armadillon/code/ga/labs/ejs-lab/views/home.ejs while compiling ejs
If I remove the exclamation point, the code works fine (ternary works as expected)
I can move on with my project, but this is REALLY bugging me. Why does the exclamation point break it?! An itch I can't scratch.
I have tried replacing the exclamation point with
&#33
!
\0021
And all of those with or without quotation marks, backticks, etc.
I expect the outpout to be "Yes, we are open!"

I think disabling Prettier made this work properly.

As @padcoding hints, this error occurs not because of the exclamation mark, but rather because of the newline. If you still want to have the newline, use (backtick) instead of"`.
